# Como hacer un select de SQL server que solo tome

Tags: sql, sql-server

Tengo en una tabla de SQL server columna PosZ

```
PosZ
103.111005555
1.55689866
95.3655523

SELECT PosZ
FROM Table
```

mi pregunta es como obtengo solo los primeros numero antes del Punto (.) 
para que de este resultado:

```
PosZ
103
1
95
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Buenas, prueba con esto:

```
PosZ
103.111005555
1.55689866
95.3655523

SELECT round(PosZ, 0)
FROM Table
```

[sql](/questions/tagged/sql)[sqlserver](/questions/tagged/sqlserver)